# How can I assign out-of-order JSON data to the constructor of a class in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor

I have some json data that I'd like to cast to a typescript object. Please consider the following:

```
item1 = {'type':'fruit', 'name':'apple', 'color':'red'},
item2 = {'name':'tiger', 'type':'animal'}
```

The items vary in the number of fields they contain and the order. I also have a class as below:

```
class Item{
    constructor(...args:any[]){
        this.name = //what should I do here
    }
```

I'm assuming since I have an unknown number of properties for each item, I should be using `(...args:any[])` but feel free to correct me if that is not a good approach. Now, my question is how can I tell the constructor to look for 'name' for instance. If things were in order, I would use `args[0], args[1]` but since they are not in order, I'm looking for something like `args['name']`

EDIT:

1. Items are added as such: `firstItem = new Item(//item details here)`
2. The info above is only an example to get the point across. In reality there are thousands of different items all in a JSON string and each item can also have subnodes, so defining a separate class for each is not an option. What all the items have in common is that they all have a 'name'.

Comment: I think my proposed answer works and meets your requirements.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? If you don't want to define classes/interface per item (because you have thousands of different ones) then why do you need a class for? You can just use the js object that you have and you can access the fields like: `item1.name`. What do you intend to do with instances of this `Item` class? Please explain your scenario better to get a more suited answer,

Comment: @GPicazo, yes it does. Thank you.

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer, your answer was educational for me but I don't have enough reps to upvote either answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear from the question, but it sounds like the `Item` class is used to create a single instance of an item. So should the class not look like:

```
// class definition
class Item {
    constructor(input:any) {
        if (input) {
            this.name = input.name;
        }
    }
}

//usage
const item1 = {'type':'fruit', 'name':'apple', 'color':'red'},
const item2 = {'name':'tiger', 'type':'animal'}

const item1Instance = new Item(item1);
const item2Instance = new Item(item2);
```

Comment: yes, Item class is used to create single instance of an Item. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interfaces to describe the items:

```
interface ItemData {
    type: string;
    name: string;
}

interface ColorItemData extends ItemData {
    color: string;
}

class Item {
    private type: string;
    private name: string;
    private color: string;

    constructor(data: ItemData | ColorItemData) {
        this.type = data.type;
        this.name = data.name;
        this.color = (data as ColorItemData).color || null;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20item1%20%3D%20%7B%20'type'%3A%20'fruit'%2C%20'name'%3A%20'apple'%2C%20'color'%3A%20'red'%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20item2%20%3D%20%7B%20'name'%3A%20'tiger'%2C%20'type'%3A%20'animal'%20%7D%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20ItemData%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ColorItemData%20extends%20ItemData%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Item%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20type%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20color%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(data%3A%20ItemData%20%7C%20ColorItemData)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.type%20%3D%20data.type%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20data.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.color%20%3D%20(data%20as%20ColorItemData).color%20%7C%7C%20null%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

You can also have a different class per item:

```
class Item {
    private type: string;
    private name: string;

    constructor(data: ItemData) {
        this.type = data.type;
        this.name = data.name;
    }
}

class ColorItem extends Item {
    private color: string;

    constructor(data: ColorItemData) {
        super(data);
        this.color = data.color;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
let item1 = new ColorItem({'type':'fruit', 'name':'apple', 'color':'red'}),
    item2 = new Item({'name':'tiger', 'type':'animal'});
```

Comment: This would work except that I have a large number of items and each can have different properties. Please see my edits in the question.